Ubuntu Wifi keeps disconnecting intermittently and don't connect afterwards
I'm using ubuntu 22.04. My wifi keeps disconnecting randomly in every two hours. And after that it don't reconnect imediately. I've to do all sorts of things to reconnect like restart my computer sometimes, forgot connection and reconnect again, turn my wifi off/on again etc.. And sometimes if reconnects automatically after 10/20 minutes of showing three dots on wifi icon.
I don't know what to do and what's the issue here. I've reinstalled my network-manager but that didn't solved the problem either.
Someone please help me with this, am I the only one whose facing this issue or is this some ubuntu bug?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Upgrade your system firmware to the latest version as soon as possible. Manufacturers mainly or only test with Windows, so bugs against other OSes go unnoticed.
(This is a Linux FAQ, which is why I often answer the same way.)
